# Visual Studio 2012 Database Project Publish Column Order

Tags: visual-studio, database-project

With a VS2012 database project can I make it ignore column order when publishing and just add the columns to the end of the table? This is a faster and safer option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's currently a way to do this with Visual Studio 2012. There is supposed to be an "Ignore column order" option in the advanced deployment settings but this option has been removed according to [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/9613187c-3abb-4fbf-91c4-a927b26f45f1). Apparently the scope of this option was confusing and Microsoft has decided to remove it until they can improve it. (The page actually claims this option was removed from SQL Server Data Tools but I believe that is wrong. I have confirmed this option exists in Visual Studio *2010* with SSDT so I believe the problem is really with VS 2012.)

For Visual Studio 2010 you'll find the setting as follows.

- When using the Publish option: Publish > Advanced > Ignore column order
- When using the Deploy option: Project properties > Debug tab > Advanced > Ignore column order

Comment: I had a look and can't see and 'Ignore Column Order'.

Comment: Sorry Craig, I just discovered that this option is missing in VS 2012. I have updated my answer accordingly. Without that option I'm not sure how you can achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: This option is not available. You can vote for it here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1221587

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437024/visual-studio-2013-sql-schema-compare-ignore-column-order). I believe [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222351/602585) provides the information you are looking for.