# Visual Studio 2013 SQL Schema Compare: Ignore Column Order

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, schema-compare

In Visual Studio 2013, is there a way to ignore column ordering when doing a Schema Compare?  I see that this feature was removed from Visual Studio 2012 (according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13848952/188740), but I'm hoping it was brought back in version 2013.

Here's a quick visual to illustrate what I'd like to ignore:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described on [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2017/03/10/sql-server-data-tools-17-0-rc-and-ssdt-in-vs2017/), `Ignore column order` is now an option in SSDT version 17.0, which is compatible with Visual Studio 2015.

> If you’ve ever had to deal with accidental data
>   motion when putting a column in the middle of a table definition,
>   you’ll know how hard this can be to spot and manage. In this release
>   you can now check the “Ignore Column Order” option in the Advanced
>   Publish Options. This will append new columns to the end of an
>   existing table rather than altering the table structure to add the
>   column in its listed position.

You can find the setting by going into the `Advanced...` button section of your publish profile, as well as in the `Advanced...` button section of the database project properties' `Debug` tab.

[image: Option in SSDT advanced publish settings to ignore column order]

You can also achieve the same effect by adding the following element to your publish.xml file:

```
<IgnoreColumnOrder>True</IgnoreColumnOrder>
```

Unfortunately I do not know of a way to have this work in Visual Studio 2013, but hopefully you have upgraded to a newer version of Visual Studio by now :)

Answer (score 3):

Ignore column order is now available in VS2015.

> Additionally, for relational and Azure SQL databases SSDT 17.0 GA includes a highly requested improvement to ignore column order in upgrade plans as well as numerous other bug fixes.

See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2017/04/19/announcing-the-general-availability-ga-release-of-ssdt-17-0-april-2017/

Answer (score 2):

The 'Ignore column order' setting is not available in visual studio 2013. There are Tentive to reintroduce this option in the future.

Sources: Microsoft

Comment: Has this feature been reintroduced yet?

Comment: I do not believe it has been added yet. Microsoft's main objective is probably still on making Windows 10 more user-friendly.

Comment: If anyone's looking for updates on this, try [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edb3abc9-e221-4e5b-b4af-c958dbe1c330/schema-comparisons-ignore-column-order?forum=ssdt) which has a couple of replies from Microsoft employees.

Comment: There's also a [user voice issue](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4198223-reintroduce-the-option-ignorecolumnorder-in-schema) about this.

Comment: This option is not available you can vote for it here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1221587

Comment: For any poor souls who end up here from Google like me, the above link has good news: "This feature has been completed and checked-in. It's currently planned to ship in the March release of SSDT.

Saturday, February 18, 2017 1:18 AM"

Answer (score 1):

This feature is also available in Azure Data studio -> Schema Compare -> Ignore Column Order.

[image]